# How can I mock a c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, sql, c3p0

I understand that C3P0 is a final class, and cannot be mocked using Mockito. I also understand that I should not be mocking out my database calls in general. However, I have a few methods in a class that requires a C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource, and I would like to mock that cpds for testing those methods.

Comment: `ComboPooledDataSource` pretty much just adds final to `AbstractComboPooledDataSource`. If you type your references as `Abstract ComboPooledDataSource`, you can generate mock subclasses to your heart's content, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following approaches for the Mockito and PowerMock:

1. [Mockito v2.1.0](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods)
2. [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockfinal)